# Android BLE startScan() function doesn't call back

Tags: java, android, function, android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a problem when using BLE API. I use the startScan() function for scanning and trying to return the results into mLeScanCallback. But I didn't know why the onScanResult() function cannot run.
Although when I make a log for checking, the program has already run through "startScan ()".
Is there anyone who can get me a suggestion?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwgHc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvEF6.png)

Comment: First, check if your devices's Location function is online. If it's disabled, your scan might not work. Second, make sure you have all your permissions achieved for the location and ble functions.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. But I quite sure that my app has enough permission. Because it works well when I tested at another project.

Comment: What about the location stuff? Are they enabled on your test device?

Comment: Actually, I tested another app with BLE API on this device and it works perfectly. So, I think the problem does not belong to the device or permissions. I think it belongs to code.